# Convert 2 rows in one in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
> mydata <- read.csv("mydata.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)
> tbl_df(mydata)
# A tibble: 16,499 x 60
   SRC_035_01  SRC_035_01.1  SRC_035_02  SRC_035_02.1
1       Force          Time       Force          Time
2     -0.0037         0.000      0.0041         0.000
3      0.0000         0.004      0.0073         0.004
4      0.0079         0.008      0.0156         0.008
5      0.0150         0.012      0.0228         0.012
6      0.0177         0.016      0.0262         0.016
7      0.0141         0.020      0.0236         0.020
8      0.0103         0.024      0.0206         0.024
9      0.0080         0.028      0.0193         0.028
10     0.0102         0.032      0.0226         0.032
```

I need to combine the first row with the header, column by column, resulting in this output:

```
# A tibble: 16,498 x 60
   SRC_035_01_Force  SRC_035_01.1_Time  SRC_035_02_Force  SRC_035_02.1_Time
2           -0.0037              0.000            0.0041              0.000
3            0.0000              0.004            0.0073              0.004
4            0.0079              0.008            0.0156              0.008
5            0.0150              0.012            0.0228              0.012
6            0.0177              0.016            0.0262              0.016
7            0.0141              0.020            0.0236              0.020
8            0.0103              0.024            0.0206              0.024
9            0.0080              0.028            0.0193              0.028
10           0.0102              0.032            0.0226              0.032
```

Anyone could give me a code hint?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please check how you read the data.  May be you should use `skip=2` i.e `df1 <- read.csv("yourdata.csv", skip=2); lines <- readLines("yourdata.csv", n=2)[2]; names(df1) <- paste0(names(df1), lines, sep="_")`  This should also avoid the problem of fixing the column types

Comment: `paste(colnames(mtcars), mtcars[1,], sep = "_")` might be useful.

Comment: Not working... in the first solution readLines outputs a vector of length 2 with all the text being one unique element, like this:
`> lines[2]
[2]"Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time(...)"`
So the column names are all like this:
`SRC_035_01_Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time,Force,Time,(...)`
Using the second way, results are so similar :(